# Statically delete object key JavaScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, tslint, delete-keyword

I'm using TypeScript along with TSLint, and I have the following code:

```
var myObj = {}
var id = "key"
myObj[id] = 1
delete myObj[id]
```

But I receive a hint from TSLint: [`Do not delete dynamically computed property keys. (no-dynamic-delete)`](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-dynamic-delete/)

*The rationale for this rule (as stated on the documentation for TSLint):*

> Deleting dynamically computed keys is dangerous and not well optimized.

---

My question is, without disabling this hint in the TSLint configuration file, how should I safely and optimally delete the `id` key in `myObj`?

Comment: https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/3648

Comment: Is it just suggesting you `delete myObj.key` without the `[]`?

Comment: @James no, `delete myObj[id]` is not the same as `dekete myObj.id`.

Comment: @AriSeyhun Please extend. Because afaik - it is exactly same (ommiting the mistypo).

Comment: @DerZinger `myObj[id]` uses the variable `id`, not the field in the object with the key of `id`. For example `let id = 'myKey'; myObj[id]` this uses `myObj.myKey` but with a variable. But `myObj.id` doesn't use any variables for the key, only the `id` field directly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

a) ignore the warning
b) use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) instead

Comment: Thanks, I went with [maps](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript-map)

Comment: Did you just set myObj[id] to an empty string?

Comment: @Winnemucca Not sure I understand your question? No, deleting a property (what the OP wants) is different from setting it to an empty string.